# Vuejs2 access firebase.auth() user infos in child component

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs2

Implemented firebase auth into a vuejs2 app.
Now I need to access the user infos into a child component.

**main.js :**

```
var app = new Vue({    



  router,    

  created() {    

    connection.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

      if(user) {    

      var usersRef = db.ref('users') 
      var userID = user.uid    

      usersRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {    

        if (!snapshot.hasChild(userID)) {    

          //setting user as new 
          usersRef.child(userID).set({    

            isNew: 1 ,
            registrationDate: Date.now()    

          })    

        }     

      });    




      } else {

        this.$router.push('/auth')

      }

     });       

    } ,    

    el: '#app',    

    template: '<app></app>',    

    components:{
      App 
      } ,
  render: h => h(App)    

 });
```

Now in a child component,

When I do :

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'
console.log(Firebase.auth())
```

I can see info in the console

[image]

In that case I can see the uid

jc : "wM3ShBwwxRWwpgVwwOx04itcQSH2"

But I cannot access it with object property .uid

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Any clue ?

Comment: could you please ellaborate on how you are accessing user info in the child component?

Comment: actually i am not accessing it. tried by using firebase.auth() as the data is here (seen in console)

Comment: What strategy do you think i should use ? props ? vuex ?

Comment: can you start a listener of the auth status changed of a listener for a specific global variable in the child element?? then probably you can assign the user firebase object you receive in the auth state changed function to a global variable and get the id using user.uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the currentUser uid, you should get it from `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`. You also need to wait for the user to be ready by setting a listener to `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: Yes it worked like this :


but i need to access it inside a component method and in that case it does not work :(